# Finding a curve - first order ODE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

> Find a curve whose tangent lines create a triangle of area $2a^2$ with the $x-$ and $y$-axes.

First off, the tangent line equation is:$$y=f'(X)(x-X)+Y$$ where $(X,Y)$ is an arbitrary point. I realize that now I have to evaluate it at $X=0$ and $Y=0$, and then multiply it and the absolute value of that must equal $4a^2$.

But I dont know how to translate what I wrote into an equation.

Im sorry for my English, its not my native language, and I try my best translating my tasks and what Im trying to do. Feel free to correct what I wrote if there are any linguistic mistakes.

Comment: it looks ok except you must take care not to confuse the rôles of what you have written as $x$ and $X$, and $y$ and $Y$. what you want is the value $y_0$ for which $x=0$ and the value $x_0$ for which $y=0$. these are obtained as functions of $X, f'(X)$ and $Y$ (from the equation you have written). then the condition $x_0y_0=4a^2$ will give you the required differential equation.

Comment: Is $Y$ equal to $f(X)$?

Comment: yes, i was going to remind you of that

Comment: So what I have to do now is substitute $x=0$ into tangent line equation and solve for $y_0$, and then substitute $y=0$ and solve for $x_0$, is that correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it may help to appreciate Achille's elegant answer if i append a more elementary treatment starting from Lugi's equation for the tangent. if $(X,Y)$ is a generic point on the solution curve, we will denote the derivative of $Y$ wrt $X$ by $Y'$ the tangent at $(X,Y)$ is then:
$$
y-Y=Y'(x-X)
$$
thus the points of intersection with the axis, $(x_0,0)$ and $(0,y_0)$ are given by:
$$
y_0= Y - XY' \\
x_0= - \frac{y_0}{Y'}
$$
and the area-of-triangle condition is:
$$
\frac12 x_0y_0 = 2a^2
$$
substituting we have
$$
(Y-XY')^2 = -4a^2Y'
$$
and upon differentiating w.r.t $X$ this becomes
$$
2(Y-XY')(Y'-Y'-XY'') = -4a^2Y''
$$
i.e.
$$
(Y-XY')XY'' = 2a^2Y''
$$
in a region where $Y'' \ne 0$ this may be written:
$$
- \left(\frac{Y}{X}\right)' = 2a^2 X^{-3}
$$
which integrates to give
$$
\frac{Y}{X} = a^2X^{-2} + c
$$
if $X \to \infty$ the triangle condition determines that $Y \to 0$ hence $c=0$ giving
$$
XY = a^2
$$

Comment: Why do you make the assumption that $Y''\neq 0$?

Comment: if $Y''=0$ on an interval then we obtain the 'trivial' family of straight-line solutions $y+sx=2a\sqrt{s}$ (parametrized by $s$).  using the method mentioned by Achille you will see that the required curve is the envelope of these lines. if $Y'' \ne 0$ on an interval then we may cancel it from both sides of the equation. the solution of the resulting equation gives the envelope itself. however my argument re the constant of integration does seem to lack rigor

Answer (score 3):

The concept you need is the [envelope of a family of curves](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Envelope_%28mathematics%29#Envelope_of_a_family_of_curves).

Given a family of curves $C_t$ parametrized by a parameter $t$. One definition of the envolope is a curve tangent
to all of the $C_t$. If you view the tangent lines of the curve you want as a family of curves, the curve you seek is the corresponding envelope.

Let's say the family of curves is given implicitly by some function $F(t,x,y)$,

$$(x,y) \in C_t\quad\iff\quad F(t,x,y) = 0$$

The envelope for $\{\;C_t\;\}$ will be given by the set of points for which

$$F(t,x,y) = \frac{\partial}{\partial t}F(t,x,y) = 0$$

Let's use the curve you seek as an example. If you are given a line of the from

$$\frac{x}{x_0} + \frac{y}{y_0} = 1\quad\text{ with }\quad x_0, y_0 > 0$$

The area it forms with the $x$ and $y$ axes are given by $\frac12 x_0 y_0$. 
If this is equal to $2a^2$, then we can find some $t$ such that 
$\displaystyle\;x_0 = \frac{2a}{t}$ and $y_0 = 2a t$. 
We can parametrize the set of tangent lines as

$$C_t :  F(t,x,y) = xt  + \frac{y}{t} - 2 a = 0$$

The condition $\displaystyle\;\frac{\partial}{\partial t}F(t,x,y) = 0\;$ becomes

$$x - \frac{y}{t^2} = 0 \quad\implies\quad t = \sqrt{y/x}$$

Substitute this back into the condition $\displaystyle\;F(t,x,y) = 0\;$, one get

$$x\sqrt{y/x} + y \sqrt{x/y} - 2a = 0 \quad\iff\quad xy = a^2$$

The curve you seek is that portion of the hyperbola $xy = a^2$ in the first quadrant.

Comment: Why is that limited only to first quadrant, and why isnt it xy=a^2 OR -xy=a^2?

Comment: In principle, you can include them. It really depends on whether you want to consider configurations where the triangle is lying in other quadrants.

Comment: Very good answer!

Answer (score 0):

We find singular solution of single parameter straight line family of Clairaut's type. The powerful C discriminant (and also P  discriminant ) are so useful, as  also mentioned by achilles  hui.

The required singular solution or envelope is the eliminant between F(x,y,u) = 0 and its partial derivative with respect to parameter u.

$ x/u + y/v = 1, u v = 4 a^2 $

Plug in v of second into first equation to eliminate it, $ x/u + y *u/ 4 a^2 = 1 ..... (1) $

Partial differentiation w.r.t. u gives$ - x/ u^2 + y/ 4 a^2 = 0 ..... (2)$

Eliminate u from (1) and (2) and simplify to get $ x y = a^2$, the desired curve as a rectangular hyperbola touching all straight lines with constant intercept product.

You can play with intercepts. For example if you want $ u^2 + v^2 = L^2 = constant$ where a ladder length L slides down y-axis keeping bottom end along x-axis, following the same steps above you get an astroid 
$ x^ {2/3} + y^ {2/3} = L^ {2/3 } $ .